# How do I store a hashed password on Django and how do i compare with another hashed password?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have been lookign for a way to store hashes but i still without finding the correct way to do it in models.py

**models.py**

```py
class QL_USR_DT(models.Model):
    ql_usr_img_link=models.ImageField(upload_to="user-profile-picture")
    ql_usr_name=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    ql_usr_email=models.EmailField()#By default the max_Length is 254
    ql_usr_pass=models.CharField(max_length=254)
    ql_usr_username=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = (
        ("M","Male"),
        ("F","Female"),
    )
    ql_usr_gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender, default="M",    null=False)
    ql_usr_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**settings.py**

```py
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using the built in authentication system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to manage the passwords yourself in your own model, you can do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password

your_password = make_password("plain_text")
check_password("plain_text",your_password)
```

And store that hash in the database.

Comment: store it in a normal CharField as the one I showed in my code?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I am not sure how long the CharField needs to be for your chosen hasher.